# Calculating the wavelength of an emitted photon of a Ne^9+ ion

Tags: physical-chemistry, energy

I'm supposed to calculate the wavelength of an emitted photon going from the 6p orbital to the 2s orbital. The first part of this problem will be to use the equation

$$E=-{Rh\over n^2}$$

in order to calculate the energy.

That's all easily done when considering a hydrogen atom. Our chemistry professor, however, has told us to consider the ion $\ce{Ne^9+}$.

Therefore, my question is this: What's the difference (if any) when calculating the energy when it comes to this specific ion? What part does the nucleus play in this?

Also side note(Just to make sure): There is no difference when the professor refers to the orbital numbers right? I'm only supposed to consider the principal quantum numbers, correct?

Comment: The equation is already wrong. That equation only applies for the hydrogen atom. For a hydrogen-like species, i.e. an ion with only one electron like $\ce{Ne^9+}$, you need to consider the effect of the nuclear charge $Z$ - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula#Rydberg_formula_for_any_hydrogen-like_element

Comment: Have you considered in class the change in wavelengths going from hydrogen to deuterium? As noted by @orthocresol, Ne$^{9+}$ is a single electron, hydrogen-like system, except that the nuclear charge and mass are not that of a proton. This does change the levels of the Rydberg states, but in a way usually covered in a straightforward way by texts or at good on-line resources.

Comment: Check [this page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula).